# Code crashing Cassini web server

Tags: c#, while-loop

Just a simple crap code. I confused with the syntax when I tried to execute that code by clicking on button, page is trying to load but it couldn't. I tried to load the same page in multiple tabs and I got error "Web server stopped working"! Can anybody correct the syntax of following simple code?

```
    string folderpath = @"C:\Users\Nouser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\folders";
    string foldername = TextBox1.Text;
    string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderpath, foldername);
    while (Directory.Exists(newPath))
    {
        foldername = foldername + ik;
        ik = ik + 1;
    }
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
```

Comment: close visual studio and try opening again

Comment: I believe its just syntax error in code.

Comment: @Madcoder.: I don't see any syntax error in that code.  If it was a syntax error, I doubt it would compile.  Do you get any compile-time errors?  Are you getting a run-time exception?  What's the error?

Comment: @MadCoder: My answer was correct, wasn't it? A little unfair me thinks.

Comment: @Digbyswift - You are correct of course! but incomplete. I clearly mentioned in my question that was confused with code and I need seeking for correction. Although you found that issue is with `While` loop I was bit confused and couldn't sort out where the issue is and mean while rally25rs corrected me. Anyways thank you :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something more like this:

```
int ik = 1;
string folderpath = @"C:\Users\Nouser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\folders";
string foldername = TextBox1.Text;
string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderpath, foldername);
while (Directory.Exists(newPath))
{
    newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderpath, foldername + ik);
    ik = ik + 1;
}
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the check `Directory.Exists(newPath)` is only ever evaluating the initial value set to newPath, so causing an endless loop.

Debug the loop by stepping through and seeing what newPath is set as upon each iteration.

Comment: Good catch.  `newPath` doesn't change within the loop, so the loop will run indefinitely.  (Or at least until `foldername` or `ik` overflows.)

Comment: No! the issue is with `While` when I change `While` to `if` everything works fine but how can I change folder name?

Comment: As I say, the check within the while() is not working as newPath never changes. You need to set newPath upon each iteration, in addition to what you are already doing.

Comment: +1. It is pretty obviously an infinite loop there. Even if it didn't infinite loop, I don't think it is doing what you intend. You would create folders named "folder", "folder0", "folder01", "folder012", etc... (assuming `ik` is an int starting at 0)